# Accessing array inside array in JSON React-Native

Tags: android, json, autocomplete, react-native

- Trying to perform autocomplete suggestion by reading JSON data.
- The format of JSON data is:

  ```
   locations: 
       [
         {
           "Companyname": "pqr",
           "TopfiveproductsList": [
             {
               "prodId": "16",
               "prodName": "abc"
             },
             {
               "prodId": "17",
               "prodName": "xyz"
             }
           ],
          "companycode": "C1"
         },
         {
          "Companyname": "zzz",    
           "TopfiveproductsList": [
             {
               "prodId": "12",
               "prodName": "yyy"
             },
             {
               "prodId": "14",
               "prodName": "lmn"
             },
            {
               "prodId": "32",
               "prodName": "qaq"
             }
           ],
           "companycode": "C2"
         }
       ]
  ```
- Displaying `companyname` from `locations` array and its corresponding records of `TopfiveproductsList` array.
  In below code `companyname` is displayed but its corresponding `TopfiveproductsList.prodName` are not displayed.
- Accessing `prodName` gives error `JSON parse error: Unexpected identifier object`.

  ```
  <Autocomplete
      autoCapitalize="none"
      autoCorrect={false} 
      data={locations}
      defaultValue={query}
      onChangeText={text => this.setState({ query: text })}
      renderItem={({ Companyname, TopfiveproductsList.prodName }) => (
          <Text>{Companyname} {TopfiveproductsList.prodName}</Text   )}
      />
  ```

**index.android.js**

```
 import Sample from './sample.json';
    export default class pre extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          locations: [],
          query: '',
        };
      }

      loadData() {
       this.setState({ locations : Sample });  
    }

      findLocation(query) {
          this.loadData();

        const { locations } = this.state;
        const regex = new RegExp(`${query.trim()}`, 'i');
        return locations.filter(location => location.Companyname.search(regex) >= 0);
      }

      render() {
        const { query } = this.state;
        const locations = this.findLocation(query);
        return (
         <View>
            <Autocomplete
              autoCapitalize="none"
              autoCorrect={false} 
              data={locations}
              defaultValue={query}
              onChangeText={text => this.setState({ query: text })}
              renderItem={({ Companyname }) => (
                  <Text> {Companyname} </Text> )}
            />
           </View>
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TopfiveproductsList is an array of objects, you can't just do TopfiveproductsList.prodName to get what you need. It looks like you need to use an array of strings so you would have to build it yourself:

```
<Autocomplete
    autoCapitalize="none"
    autoCorrect={false} 
    data={locations}
    defaultValue={query}
    onChangeText={text => this.setState({ query: text })}
    renderItem={({ Companyname, TopfiveproductsList }) => {
        const prodNames = TopfiveproductsList.map(item => item.prodNames);
        return <Text>{Companyname} {prodNames}</Text   }}
    />
```

Comment: it gives error `r.render(): A valid React element(or null)must be returned. You may have returned undefined,an array or some other invalid object.`

Comment: oh my bad, you have to change it to `return <Text>...</Text>`, I just updated my answer

Comment: Thanks. I want to add ToucableOpacity too. I tried doing this `return  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({ query: Companyname})}>  <Text>{Companyname} {prodNames}</Text> </TouchableOpacity> } ` but it gave error `rawtext must be wrapped in explicit <text>component`

Comment: hmm that's a little weird since it is wrapped in a text component, try this: `Text>``${Companyname} ${prodNames}``</Text> `

Comment: take out one of those backticks  on each side though

Comment: I solved it using`return(<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({ query: searchString })}><Text style={styles.itemText}> {searchString} {prodNames}</Text></TouchableOpacity>);` Thanks for the help

Comment: I  tried various ways to add up code like if block ,for loop inside return statement but it throws error. Isn't it possible?