# Iterate through nested arrays in native-base and display the content on multiple lines using List

Tags: arrays, json, react-native, native-base

I am quite new to react-native and native-base. 
**I would like to access 'description' inside the data array  in below JSON response using List in React-Native and display them as different ListItems.**

**JSON file(data.js):**

```
[
    {
        object: 'list',
        data: 
        [
        {
            id: 'cust1',
            object: 'customer',
            account_balance: 0,
            created: 1514549772,
            currency: 'usd',
            description: 'CustomerName1',
            discount: null,
            email: null,
            subscriptions: {
                object: 'list',
                data: [],
                has_more: false,
                total_count: 0,
                url: '/v1/customers/cust1/subscriptions'
            }
        },
        {
            id: 'cust2',
            object: 'customer',
            account_balance: 0,
            created: 1514549772,
            currency: 'usd',
            description: 'CustomerName2',
            discount: null,
            email: null,
            subscriptions: {
                object: 'list',
                data: [],
                has_more: false,
                total_count: 0,
                url: '/v1/customers/cust2/subscriptions'
            }
        },
        ],
        has_more: false,
        url: "/v1/customers"
    }
]
```

**My code:**

```
export default class CustomersScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log(customers);
    return (
      <Container style={styles.container}>
        <Content>
          <List
            dataArray={customers}
            renderRow={({ object, data }) => {
              const customerName = data.map(item => item.description);  
              return (
              <ListItem>
                <Text>{customerName}</Text>
              </ListItem>)}}
          />
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

I was able to access the 'description' inside the data array with the help of this post [Accessing array inside array in JSON React-Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42209439/accessing-array-inside-array-in-json-react-native)

**However, the data is getting displayed as:**

CustomerName1CustomerName2     -> same line

**instead of** (different lines as below)

CustomerName1

CustomerName2

---

**Here is how i fixed the issue of displaying the 'description' in the nested array on multiple lines:**

```
<Content>
    {
        customers.map((rowData, i) => {
        return(
            <List
                dataArray={rowData.data}
                key={i}
                renderRow={(item, k) => {
                const customerName = item.description; 
                return (
                <ListItem key={item.id}>
                    <Text>{customerName}</Text>
                </ListItem>)}}
            />)
        })
    }
</Content>
```

Comment: I have managed to make it work to display the CustomerNames(i.e. description) on multiple lines with the nested array using List.  The updated code fix is in the issue description above. I would be glad to have a better solution if it is there